# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, gmail-api, credentials

for a week I have been using the Gmail API without problem, but I don't know why since yesterday an error appeared while initializing this API: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: unexpected end of data. I remember opening the credentials.json file in notepad ++ but I have checked the encoding and it is in utf-8. I know that the error comes from a specific line of code:

```
else:
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        'credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

But no matter how hard I try, I can nowhere find a solution to my problem on internet ....
Here is the original code from the gmail api python doc: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python?authuser=1

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this this the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Noste\Project\untitled0.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Noste\Project\untitled0.py", line 29, in main
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

  File "C:\Users\noste\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google_auth_oauthlib\flow.py", line 457, in run_local_server
    local_server = wsgiref.simple_server.make_server(

  File "C:\Users\noste\anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 154, in make_server
    server = server_class((host, port), handler_class)

  File "C:\Users\noste\anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()

  File "C:\Users\noste\anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)

  File "C:\Users\noste\anaconda3\lib\http\server.py", line 140, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)

  File "C:\Users\noste\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 756, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 8: unexpected end of data
```

I run this code on Spyder 4.2.0 which run on python 3.8.
Thanx for help !

Comment: Can you inspect that with a debugger and see what is stored in `name`? Also, can you read 'credentials.json'and decode it as utf8, or does that fail?

Comment: When i try to read credentials.json with "with open('credentials.json, encoding="utf-8")" and i print this , it works fine.

Comment: That means that the encoding problem does not come from credentials.json. You should see what is in `name`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. It was a problem with my PC... It stopped working 1 hour later.